# Selenium Script For IE

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium-rc

I got this error , while running selenium script for Internet Explorer 9.

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Protected Mode must be set to the same value (enabled or disabled) for all zones. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information); duration or timeout: 193 milliseconds
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a bug report discussing this issue: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1795

> If you turn ON protected mode in ALL Internet Explorer Zones (Security Tab in IE settings) I believe the issue is resolved.

Comment: Thanks its works , but another exception occurs:
org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
Sep 30, 2011 1:49:35 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: Retrying request

Comment: If you get another exception, you should open a bug report at the selenium website.

Answer (score 0):

```
DesiredCapabilities ieCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
ieCapabilities.setCapability(
    InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,
    true
); 
WebDriver dr = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieCapabilities);
```

Comment: +1. This works perfectly for me, and better to do it programmatically than changing browser settings if you want to port your test cases.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it through code here is why
http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-protected-mode-and.html

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriver driver = null;
@BeforeSuite
public void suiteSetup() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
}

//Simply create some blank annotations over here for validation purpose
@BeforeTest
public void testSetup() {
    
}

@BeforeMethod
public void methodSetup() {
    
}

@Test

public void testMethod1() throws IOException {
  FileInputStream  file = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Leave_Details.xlsx");
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(file);// .xslx file
```

HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(file);- .xsl file

```
    XSSFSheet sh = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");
```

HSSFSheet sh = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");// Sheet1 need to be replaced with actual tab name
System.out.println(sh.getRow(0).getCell(0).getStringCellValue()); // Gives the data. need to update the row and column numbers accordingly

```
    driver.get("url");
    //Get the title of the application
    String strTitle = driver.getTitle();
    System.out.println("Title of the page:"+strTitle);
    
    //No of elements 
    List<WebElement> listElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("")); // Use findelemet'S' not findelement
    System.out.println(listElements.size());
    
}
@Parameters ({"Type","Name"}) // Add name of parameters added in testng.xml and give name over here and do the same naming in method
@Test
public void testMethod2(String strType, String strName) {
    System.out.println(strType); //Gives the parameter value specified in testng.xml
}

@AfterTest
public void testTearDown() {
    
}

@AfterMethod
public void methodTearDown() {
    
}

@AfterSuite
public void suiteTearDown() {
    driver.close();
}
```

Comment: File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
// Now you can do whatever you need to do with it, for example copy somewhere
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("c:\\tmp\\screenshot.png"));

Comment: driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
driver.switchTo().alert().getText();   
driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("Text");

Comment: TakesScreenshot scrShot =((TakesScreenshot)webdriver); //Call getScreenshotAs method to create image file File SrcFile=scrShot.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE); //Move image file to new destination File DestFile=new File(fileWithPath); //Copy file at destination FileUtils.copyFile(SrcFile, DestFile);

Comment: <parameter name="browser" value="Firefox"/>
 <parameter name="username" value="testuser"/>
 <parameter name="password" value="testpassword"/>

Comment: @Test  
@Parameters({ "username", "password" })
public void testCaseTwo(String username, String password) {
driver.findElement(By.xpath("")).sendKeys(username);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("")).sendKeys"password");

Comment: static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("Demo16_Basic_Configurator.class");
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
        WebDriver driver;
    BasicConfigurator.configure();
  
    driver.get("url");
    logger.info("Opening Pack and Go application");

Comment: Parameter in Testng xml:
<parameter name = "myName" value="manisha"/> 
@Parameters({ "username", "password" }) 
@Test 
public void testCaseTwo(String username, String password) { 
System.out.println("Parameter for User Name passed as :- " + username); 
System.out.println("Parameter for Password passed as :- " + password);
}

Comment: WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); //Creating an object of FirefoxDriver
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("https://www.google.com/");

Comment: Try below code, this will print all cells data,
// Grab the table 
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.id("divListView")); 

// Now get all the TR elements from the table 
List<WebElement> allRows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr")); 

// And iterate over them, getting the cells 
for (WebElement row : allRows) { 
    List<WebElement> cells = row.findElements(By.tagName("td")); 

    // Print the contents of each cell
    for (WebElement cell : cells) { 
        System.out.println(cell.getText());
    }
}

Comment: Logger: Trace < Debug < Info < Warn < Error < Fatal.
Static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(“classname.class”);
Public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
webDriver driver;
BasicConfigurator.configure();
Logger.info(“opening application”);

No of hyperlinks
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
System.out.println(links.size());

Comment: Specific text exists: 
String bodyText = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getText();
Assert.assertTrue("Text not found!", bodyText.contains(text));
If( boxyText.contains(text) == “specifictext”) {
Syso.print(“”);
}
Else
System.out.println(“”);

WebElement textDemo = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Write and Earn']"));
 
if(textDemo.isDisplayed())
{
System.out.println("Element found using text");
}

else
System.out.println("Element not found");
}

Comment: Table data:
//No.of Columns
        List  col = wd.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id=\"leftcontainer\"]/table/thead/tr/th"));
        System.out.println("No of cols are : " +col.size()); 
        //No.of rows 
        List  rows = wd.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='leftcontainer']/table/tbody/tr/td[1]")); 
        System.out.println("No of rows are : " + rows.size());

Comment: Specific row and column data: 3rd row and 2nd column
//To find third row of table
   WebElement tableRow = baseTable.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"leftcontainer\"]/table/tbody/tr[3]"));
         String rowtext = tableRow.getText();
   System.out.println("Third row of table : "+rowtext);
      
      //to get 3rd row's 2nd column data
      WebElement cellIneed = tableRow.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"leftcontainer\"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]"));
      String valueIneed = cellIneed.getText();
      System.out.println("Cell value is : " + valueIneed);

Comment: //To verify if name risetop exists or not
Public static String cellTex;
List<WebElement> tableRows=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr"));
int rowsize=tableRows.size();
System.out.println(rowsize);
List<WebElement> tableCol=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table/thead/tr/th"));
for(int i=1;i<rowsize;i++){
      
      for(int j=1;j<colSize;j++){
            WebElement firstIndex=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td["+j+"]"));
if(j==1){
      cellTex=cellTex+firstIndex.getText();
      System.out.println(cellTex);      
       }
            }
      }

Comment: if(cellTex.contains("Risetop")){
      System.out.println("Name EXISTS");
}
else{
      System.out.println("Doesnt Exist");
}

Comment: //get complete table data

for(int i=1;i<rowsize;i++){
      
      for(int j=1;j<colSize;j++){
            WebElement firstIndex=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td["+j+"]"));
      cellTex=cellTex+firstIndex.getText();
      System.out.println(cellTex);
      
            }
            }

Comment: excel utility - right click src->new package com.test.utility. then new class with ExcelUtils.https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/testng-data-provider-excel/

Comment: Import java.util.ArrayList;
Import com.excel.utility.Xls_Reader;
public class TestUtil {
static Xls_Reader reader;
public static ArrayList<Object[]> getDataFromExcel(){
ArrayList<Object[]> myData = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
try{
reader= new Xls_Reader(“/Users/documents/testdata.xlsx”);
} catch (Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}

Comment: for ( int rowNum=2;rowNum<=reader.gerRowCount(“sheetnameinexcel”);rowNum++){
String firstName = reader.getCellData(“sheetname”, “firstname”, rowNum);
String lastName = reader.getCellData(“sheetname”, “lastname”, rowNum);
Object ob[] = { firstName, lastName};
myData.add(ob);
}
return myData;
}
}

Comment: @DataProver
public Iterator<Object[]> getTestData(){
ArrayList<Object[]> testData = Testutil.getDataFromExcel();
Return testData.iterator();
}

Comment: @Test(dataProvider=”getTestData”)
Public void sampleTest(String firstName, String lastName){

Comment: String assertionString = “testing”;
SoftAssert softAssert=new SoftAssert();
softAssert.assertEquals(“testing”, assertionString);

Comment: sh1.getRow(0).createCell(2).setCellValue("2.41.0");
 
 sh1.getRow(1).createCell(2).setCellValue("2.5");
 
 sh1.getRow(2).createCell(2).setCellValue("2.39");https://learn-automation.com/read-and-write-excel-files-in-selenium/

Comment: /@BeforeSuite
/@AfterSuite
/@BeforeTest
/@AfterTest
/@BeforeGroups
/@AfterGroups
/@BeforeClass
/@AfterClass
/@BeforeMethod
/@AfterMethod

Answer (score 0):

```
File src=new File("filepath/excelsheetname.xlsx");

// load file
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(src);

// Load workbook
XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

// Load sheet- Here we are loading first sheetonly
XSSFSheet sh1= wb.getSheetAt(0);

// getRow() specify which row we want to read.
// and getCell() specify which column to read.
// getStringCellValue() specify that we are reading String data.

System.out.println(sh1.getRow(0).getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
System.out.println(sh1.getRow(0).getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
System.out.println(sh1.getRow(1).getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
System.out.println(sh1.getRow(1).getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
System.out.println(sh1.getRow(2).getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
System.out.println(sh1.getRow(2).getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
```

Comment: /@BeforeSuite
/@BeforeTest
/@BeforeClass
/@BeforeMethod
/@Test
/@AfterMethod
/@AfterClass
/@AfterTest
/@AfterSuite